# How do I insert an actual TAB in Komodo Edit 6.1

Tags: komodo

I am editing a Debian `rules` file (which uses makefile syntax) and need to insert an actual TAB character. However, pressing tab inserts four spaces as per my usual preferences (there is no indentation at all in the file so far). Checking the box **Edit » Current File Settings... » Editor » Indentation » Prefer Tab characters over spaces** makes no difference.

So how do I insert a tab character?

Comment: I've been using Komodo for a long time, and was quite annoyed at the beginning by tabs handling. To my knowledge, it's not possible.

Comment: @jeromeG It's weird, since it's such holy war material... you'd expect *some* concession to be made.

Comment: I agree, I actually use Notepad++ as well when I do want my tabs. The edit menu of notepad++ is simpler and actually does what it suggests with regard to tabs. Looking forward to see some answers on this one.

Comment: @detly the steps you describe in your original question work correctly in Komodo 7.1.3  I assume it was just a bug before

Comment: @mndrix - Yes, I think they overhauled their rules for how documents inherit whitespace settings, and this cleared up some bugs and inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have checked **Insert tab after spaces** you need to set **Number of spaces per indent** and **Width of each Tab character** to the same value (e.g. 4 and 4 instead of the default 4 and 8).

Comment: Sorry for the delay :) All I can say is, W. T. F.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

For the impatient, skip to the summary or read on for a little more detail in addition to the summary provided.

This is a long-ago question but I think it deserves an update because Komodo's indent settings can be confusing to many. When editing files in Komodo it can get messy if you want to change your indentation preferences after the fact. This answer pertains to Komodo 8 (should work with 9 too). The following will help you to not pull your hair out at your desk:

- Do (almost) everything that the other people answered above (I am not repeating what has already been said).
- (Important!) If you notice things do not change after changing settings, that's because Komodo by default saves the editor preferences for each document you work with. If you want to change it for that document, or others, you can either turn that feature off immediately after installing, or access each one's settings. Here's one way to do it:

### To make the indentation settings GLOBAL

After installing komodo, go to **Edit->Preferences** and select the **Editor->Indentation** category. UNCHECK the **Allow file contents to override Tab and indentation settings**. There, now you have only to deal with the global and per-programming-language settings shown on that page (like mentioned in the other answers). IF YOU HAVE ALREADY OPENED AND SAVED DOCUMENTS, like most people, you'll have to delete the per-file settings (unfortunately, in a compiled xmlc file). The summary  below explains where and how to do this.

### To change the indentation settings on a file-by-file basis

Find the offending document and open it, in the code editor window, right click to get your popup context menu, select **File Properties and Settings**. Select the Editor->Indentation category. Look familiar? Yes it's a cut-down version of the global editor settings with just document-specific settings. These are the settings that matter once you've opened a file If you disabled this feature already then you don't have to worry about this. However, if you CHANGE things here after the fact, **they will still take precedence over your global settings!**

### Summary

Settings for each document are saved individually

- Access those settings by right clicking on 'File properties and settings'
- These settings are set to whatever the 'Preferences' are set to by default
- Indent and Spacing should be set to the same value to avoid the dreaded half-tab
- Disabling the 'file settings' on one file does NOT disable them on another
- Disabling the 'file settings' globally only affects first-time-opened documents
- To reset prefs for all documents; delete the doc-state.xmlc file in $HOME/.komodo/[version]/ (do this at your *OWN* risk!).
- Remember, setting file-specific settings even after this will *override* your global settings, you will have to delete the files again to reset them again if that should happen.

Once you have removed per-file settings (or right after installing komodo)

- Run komodo, and for heaven's sake don't open any documents (yet)
- Select Edit->Preferences and go to the Editor->Indentation category
- UNCHECK the **Allow file contents to override Tab and indentation settings** checkbox
- Follow the answers provided above
- Take a break and relax, all is right in the universe!

I recommend backup of your *.xml and *.xmlc files in ~/.komodo/8.5 (or whatever) on a regular basis. By backup I mean cloud storage, as USB and other physical medias are not as reliable (in reality that is).

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom right corner of Komodo, look for the phrase "Soft Tabs". Click it, then uncheck "Tabs as Spaces", and check the number above it to set the tab size.